# Nuxt 3 Pinia persisted state

Tags: nuxtjs3, pinia

I am using [pinia-plugin-persistedstate](https://prazdevs.github.io/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/frameworks/nuxt-3.html) in my Nuxt 3 application. I have setup my store according to the `Usage` section and I can see my store's state is being persisted in my browser's cookie.

However, the store persisted is always the initial value of my store. Any new value added/updated to my store's state is not being persisted. Did I miss out anything?

Comment: Have you added pinia and the persisted state plugin to your modules object in nuxt.config.js?

Comment: @GaryThomas yes. Pinia store and persisted state is working, just that for some reason the state persisted is only the initial value of my store. Subsequent updates to the state value is not persisted

Comment: It would be better if you can provide us an example of you how implement it on your end, you can use Stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:

```
  persist: {
    storage: persistedState.cookies
  }
```

to your pinia stores?
It is sometimes necessary so Nuxt generates the cookies properly